# Apt-get blocks because of broken dependencies (libc6, Linux Mint)

Tags: linux, linux-mint, apt

Currently, Apt-get completely blocks because of some unresolved dependencies, when I run an upgrade I get this error:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done                                                                                                        
Building dependency tree                                                                                                             
Reading state information... Done                                                                                                    
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.                                                                         
The following packages have unmet dependencies:                                                                                      
 gcc-4.8-multilib : Depends: libc6-dev-i386 (>= 2.11) but it is not installed                                                        
 libc6-dev-x32 : Depends: libc6-dev-i386 (= 2.19-0ubuntu6.5) but it is not installed                                                 
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

If I run the -f install option I get this error-message:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libc6-dev-i386
Recommended packages:
  gcc-multilib
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libc6-dev-i386
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 96 not upgraded.
27 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,151 kB of archives.
After this operation, 6,337 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 190746 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libc6-dev-i386_2.19-0ubuntu6.5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libc6-dev-i386 (2.19-0ubuntu6.5) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6-dev-i386_2.19-0ubuntu6.5_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/gnu', which is also in package libc6-dev-amd64 2.19-0ubuntu6.5
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6-dev-i386_2.19-0ubuntu6.5_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have no idea what to do to solve this, I can't even remove packages because of this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, yes.  The fun of dependencies, a necessary evil.

You might want to try using *dpkg* instead of *apt*.

> In certain contexts debian packages are reluctant to install using gdebi or software center [also apt & synaptic] due to dependencies problem. In that case, you can install .deb file using following command,
>
> dpkg --force-all -i PackageName
>
> e.g. dpkg --force-all -i google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb
>
> Reference:  http://linuxhalwa.blogspot.co.uk/2013/12/how-to-force-install-deb-package.html.

In your case, *dpkg --force-all -i libc6-dev-i386* might just do the trick.